# Delegate methods of XmppReconnect not called

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, reconnect

I am activating `xmppReconnect` on `xmppStream` but delegate methods of `reconnect` are not being called if I have no network connection hence attempt to connect is not made even if network is available again.

```
 _xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
[_xmppReconnect activate:_xmppStream];
[_xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

- (BOOL)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender shouldAttemptAutoReconnect:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)reachabilityFlags
{
   NSLog(@"shouldAttemptAutoReconnect:%u",reachabilityFlags);
   return YES;
}

- (void)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)connectionFlags
{
     NSLog(@"didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:%u",connectionFlags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `Reachability` you can be sure of getting notified about network status changes & hence reliably perform your operations.
 Read: [Determining Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_ReachConnect/SC_ReachConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH204-BHAFBAHI)